# Xamarin debugging issue

Tags: debugging, xamarin

We are using the Indie Version on Windows 10:

- We can build the project, but cannot debug it, the debugger button is not available and the device is always setted to DEFAULT;

Any clues?
Thanks a lot
Daniel

Comment: Is it an Android project?

Comment: If it is an  Android, you need to download the [Xamarin Android Player](https://xamarin.com/android-player) so you can debug you app on an emulator.